# IdToken not signed with AzureAD

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using Azure AD Connect for authentication & permissioning with OpenId Connect.

I dont understand why I receive a JWT IdToken **without** signature and an AccessToken **with** signature from Azure. This is probably due to the "alg=none" property set for IdToken. But why not signing the IdToken too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are getting the ID Token directly from Azure's token endpoint? If so, the communication is secured and the host is authenticated via TLS/HTTPS so there's no need to sign or integrity protect the ID Token, which is intended only you (your client).

Comment: So if I understand only the AccessToken is signed because it could be pass to another app which should be able to check the integrity of the token content. Is that right?

Comment: Steven, are you working with native clients? In the next update to the service, the id_tokens for publc clients will be signed, too. For confidential clients all id_tokens should already be signed (though what Brian said is accurate, of course - when you are getting the token from the token endpoint you don't need to check the signature)